# Right menu breaking after small device responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, menu

after resizing my bootstrap webpage to small (when 3 menu lines appears) devices and clicking on the menu button right menu items apparently shows in lower position as you can see that in snippet. But is there possible way to have this menu in some more better place?

```css
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-nav.navbar-right {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a:hover {
  color: #0295d5;
}

.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-nav.navbar-right li {
  padding-top: 4px;
} 
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-nav.navbar-right .glyphicon {
  font-size: 24px;
}
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-nav.navbar-right li {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-nav.navbar-right li:not(:first-child):before {
  content: " | ";
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.mail .badge.danger {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0185BF;
  border-color: #0183BC;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  top: -4px;
  right: -8px;
}

.navbar-nav {
  padding: 10px;
}

.header_teacher {
  background-image: url(../img/header_02.png);
  height: 217px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  background-color: #038DC9;
}

.profile_picture {
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.description {
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  float: none;
  margin-top: -125px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.attention {
  text-align: center;
}
.body_font {
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.attention {
 align: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">

<title>Teacher control panel</title>
<div class="body_font">
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
        <div class="logo">
          <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Homepage">
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>


    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Find undervisning</a>
          <li><a href="#">Om os</a>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
      </ul>
      <div class="divider">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Support</button>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope mail" aria-hidden="true">
                           <span class="badge danger">5</span>
            </span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true">
                       </span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Elever</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Kalendar</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Undervisning</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Beskeder</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Min konto</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>




  <div class="header_teacher">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="profile_picture">
        <img src="img/profile_picture.png">
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        <h1><strong>Mona Larsen</strong></h1>
        <p>Underviser hos musikundervisning.dk siden 1. august 2015</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="attention" align="left">
    <p>Hej Mona, Godt at se dig igen - din næste undervisnigstime er: <a href="#"> 27. maj 2016 </a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Kommende undervisnings lektioner</div>
      <table width="80%" border="0" align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
          <tr class="breadcrumb">
            <b><th width="15%" scope="col">Dato</th></b>
            <b><th width="15%" scope="col">Tidspunkt</th></b>
            <b><th width="15%" scope="col">Elev</th></b>
            <b><th width="35%" scope="col">Sted</th></b>
            <b><th width="20%" scope="col">Note</th></b>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>13/08/16</td>
            <td>kl. 13.15</td>
            <td>Martins Dubrowski</td>
            <td>Graven 16b st. -8000 Aarhus C</td>
            <td><a href="#">Læs note</a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>15/03/15</td>
            <td>kl. 16.30</td>
            <td>Martins Dubrowski</td>
            <td>Graven 16b st.-8000 Aarhus C</td>
            <td>---</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>16/12/14</td>
            <td>kl. 12.00</td>
            <td>Sonia Hald</td>
            <td>Graven</td>
            <td><a href="#">Læs note</a></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>
       <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <!-- Default panel contents -->
                    <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading</div>
                    <!-- List group -->
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-push-12">
                        <pre class="text-justify">zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzZ
                    zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzZ
                    zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzZ
                    zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzZ  </pre>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-push-12">
                        <pre class="text-justify"> AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAa                 
                    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAa
                    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAa
                    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAa</pre>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                <pre class="text-justify"> 
                         OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB 
                         OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB 
                         OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB 
                         OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB 
                         OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB 
                         OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB 
                         OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB 

        </pre>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem / question...

Comment: Try to resize the window when menu button appears. Looks, the right menu items are now below Main menu. How to how to make my right menu appear on main page just below the header (where the logo and menu button is) not in menu it self?

Comment: if I understand you correctly, all you need to do is change the order of your `<div class="divider">` element with your `<ul class="nav navbar-nav">` element. Lemme know if that works for you...

Comment: Nothing really changes @Narxx . Right menu items only goes in rows now not in columns as I need. Is there any way to make the right-nav go below header after shrinking the browser?

Comment: I must have not understood you. Please attach images of the current (bad) state, and a mock-up of the state you want to get...

Comment: @Narxx take a look http://imgur.com/aphEAf7
and this is what i want (showing right menu when menu button is NOT pressed)
and this is  how i want http://imgur.com/ymMXMAe

Answer (score 0):

I really hope I got the issue right.

Your problem is happening because of bootstrap's default value:

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
  .navbar-nav>li {
    float: left;
  }
}
```

So each `li` element that is a direct child of `.navbar-nav`, will get `float: left` for medium screen size (minimum view-port width of 768px).

Smaller resolutions do not get this property, and there for each `li` element takes up 100% of the width of its container, causing each element to have his own "row".

You can override this by simply giving those elements `pull-left` class (part of bootstrap) which will force them to always have the `float: left` properties.

Edit:

More specifically, change this code:

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Support</button>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope mail" aria-hidden="true">
                       <span class="badge danger">5</span>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true">
                    </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

to this:

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="pull-left">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Support</button>
      </li>
      <li class="pull-left">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope mail" aria-hidden="true">
                       <span class="badge danger">5</span>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li class="pull-left">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true">
                    </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Could you please add fiddle of code? I try to get this done but it seems like nothing takes the effect

Comment: I have played with the DOM on your example. I didn't bother copying it to jsFiddle (if you do it, I can edit there and save a new copy). Simply find the element `<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">` and add to each of its' `<li>` childs the attribute: `class="pull-left"`